# Matching sentence exactly 4 times

Tags: python, regex

I have this pattern

```
    Calibration attempts: 0
    Successful calibrations: 0
    Calibration attempts: 0
    Successful calibrations: 0
```

And I need a regex which will match this exactly like it is. This shouldn't match at all:

```
    Calibration attempts: 1
    Successful calibrations: 0
    Calibration attempts: 0
    Successful calibrations: 0
```

So far I've only come up with this, but it looks nasty.

```
(.*Calibration attempts: 0\n.*Successful calibrations: 0\n.*Calibration attempts: 0\n.*Successful calibrations: 0.*)
```

Comment: Why not use `\s+` (for one or more whitespaces) rather than `.*`  (which matches everything).

Comment: You can shorten it by matching the first half twice, but not much else can be done IMHO:
`^(Calibration attempts: 0\n\s+Successful calibrations: 0\n\s*?){2}$`

Comment: @Papooch I've edited the pattern after verifying the response that I'm getting. Would it be possible to use your solution including newlines?
EDIT: I've come up with this, looks that it works:
^(\s+Calibration attempts: 0\n\s+Successful calibrations: 0\n\s*?){2}$

Comment: If you want an exact match why not just use `==`?

Comment: @Nick I am using this regex as one of the arguments in robot framework keyword, sorry for misleading with python tag (though technically Python works under the hood here)

Answer (score 2):

This should work: `(^[\t ]+(Calibration|Successful| |attempts|calibrations)+: 0$\n?){4}`

Check out regex101.com, and there you can make test.
I tested this case for not matching anything that is not '0'

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking about negative regex but couldn't do it. It seems to work well though I'll need some further testing.